# ¿Como eliminar registros de un xlsx con c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy realizando un ejercicio donde tengo que eliminar registros con un valor especifico y lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Ruta del archivo Excel
        string filePath = "RutaDeMiArchivo";

        // Valor específico que quieres filtrar
        string valueToFilter = "AMEC0002";
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

        // Cargar el archivo Excel
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
            if (worksheet != null)
            {
                // Obtener el número de columnas utilizadas en la hoja de trabajo
                int columnCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

                // Obtener el índice de la columna que deseas filtrar
                int columnIndex = 2; // Cambiar 1 al índice de la columna específica

                // Obtener el rango de celdas en la columna especificada
                var columnCells = worksheet.Cells[2, columnIndex, worksheet.Dimension.End.Row, columnIndex];

                // Filtrar las celdas con el valor específico
                var filteredCells = columnCells.Where(cell => cell.Text != valueToFilter);


                    // Iterar sobre las celdas filtradas y mostrar sus valores
                    foreach (var cell in filteredCells)
                    {
                        if (cell.Text != valueToFilter)
                            worksheet.DeleteRow(cell.Start.Row);
                        
                    }

                package.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No se encontró ninguna hoja de trabajo en el archivo Excel.");
            }
        }
}
```

No se por que razón no toma todos y se sale del `foreach`, entonces lo que hice fue aumentar el siguiente código:

```
 int count = filteredCells.Count();

 for( int i = 0; i != count; i ++)
 {
   // Iterar sobre las celdas filtradas y mostrar sus valores
   foreach (var cell in filteredCells)
   {
     if (cell.Text != valueToFilter)
     worksheet.DeleteRow(cell.Start.Row);
                        
    }
  }
```

Lo que hice es asignar el numero de los registros a una variable que se encontraron los cuales no son iguales al valor buscado, me funciona bien pero cuando ya son demasiados registros se tarda un poco en el proceso, ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo mas eficiente? Espero me puedan apoyar.